# Angular 2 keeps adding "/testing" to the end of my file imports - systemjs

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-testing

I've just started to add unit tests to my angular 2 app and I am having a nightmare, every time I have to import something new into my app that I haven't used before, it adds "/testing" to the end of each import:

eg:

```
localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js/testing 404 (Not Found)
```

It is driving me nuts because I fix one of that error and then the same thing happens to another file import when I need to import something else.

current full error:

```
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js/testing 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:1382ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:245Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:171(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1405send @ VM1624:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1051(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1781ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:518(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1780(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2809(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3387(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3701(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4093(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4556(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4825(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:407ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
zone.js:232 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js/testing(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:339
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js/testing 404 (Not Found)
```

I've been trying to fix it by adding lines like this to my systmejs.config.js:

`'@angular/core/testing': "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js",` each time a new error like it arises and it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't but it is taking a long time regardless - is there something wrong with my systemjs.config.js?:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'js/app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/core/testing': "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js",
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-google-maps': 'npm:angular2-google-maps',
      'angular2-google-map-auto-complete' : 'npm:angular2-google-map-auto-complete', 
      'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:ng2-bs3-modal',
      "ng2-popover": "npm:ng2-popover",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js"
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      "node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal": {
        defaultExtension: 'js' 
      },
      'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core': { 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        main: 'index.js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the `testing` packages to the testing files. For instance, look your core module configuration

```
'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
'@angular/core/testing': "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js",
```

Here, `@angular/core/testing` is mapped to the `core-testing.umd.js` file. Now look at you compiler module configuration

```
'@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
```

There's no corresponding `testing` configuration. So when a file tries to import

```
import { Something } from '@angular/compiler/testing`
```

it takes `@angular/compiler` from the available mapping (`compiler.umd.js`) and adds the `testing` at the end. This doesn't happen with the core module, because there is a `testing` mapping.

So what you need to do is create the correct mappings for both the compiler module and the common module. If you look in the example in the [`karma-test-shim` of the quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/karma-test-shim.js#L40), you'll see all the different testing modules available.

```
'@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
'@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
'@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
'@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
'@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
'@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
```